# Preventing Java from creating new processes

Tags: java, bash, minecraft

I am setting up a little service to allow people to run temporary Minecraft servers on a spare box that's not being put to much use.

The .jar that will start up the Minecraft server will be uneditable, as in they can't upload a new .jar and run that in its place. However, the .jar will be the Bukkit Mod/Wrapper for Minecraft servers, which allows the loading of plugins that are in the form of .jars. What's stopping someone from creating their own plugin and using it to spawn more servers?

How can I prevent someone from using a server plugin to create another server process? I am already planning to make it so that each server will be ran under it's own user account, which wont be accessible to login from.

Comment: Look into `ulimit` which lets you limit the resources available to a user. Also, the Java security model should let you limit what a Java program can do (ex. Java applets can't access the file system by default), although I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Minecraft code base.

However you should look into running the code with a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). This will enable you restrict many operations (such as being able to exec a new process).

Done correctly, this should enable you to completely lock down the loaded .jar file. It's possible that the Minecraft server does this for you already, it's a fairly obvious thing to want to restrict the activities of downloadable mods.

Answer (score 0):

In linux there is a file called /etc/security/limits.conf.

Read this: http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf.

nproc would limit the number of processes for the user/domain.